# HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

When I access my localhost of my machine I get the following screen

[image]

whereas when I try the same in my server, I getting the following error

> HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden The page you are trying to access is
>   secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

I tried replacing http to https, but I am seeing the directory browsing.  How to configure the localhost in server to change the screen.

> **My machine:**
>     OS: Windows 8
>     IIS version: 8
>
> **My server machine:**
>      OS: Windows 2012 server
>      IIS version: 8

Please share your suggestions

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It appears you have set "required SSL" for the site and have not assigned a certificate to it.

You have 2 options:

**Option 1. Remove "require SSL" from the site using the following instructions:**

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on your website
3. Click on the "SSL Settings" in the "IIS" section
4. Uncheck "Require SSL"

**Option 2. Associate a certificate to your site:**

Have a look [here](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=8713)

Comment: Thanks, but this a the localhost right?  how and where can I change the SSL of localhost

Comment: It should be the same for localhost. You can use a self signed cert for local host. Have a look at this blog post [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Remove "require SSL" from the site using the following instructions:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on your website
3. Click on the "SSL Settings" icon
4. Uncheck "Require SSL"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have selected "Require SSL" settings in the IIS. You need to remove it.

Please use the following steps to fix this error.

> Open IIS.
>
> Select your website which has the issue.
>
> Click on the SSL Settings.
>
> Untick the "Require SSL" option.